# How can I manually set custom sound card device for espeak in C++?

Tags: c++, espeak

I have already written following codes and the program can speak.

```
    espeak_Initialize(AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK, 0, NULL, 0);    
    espeak_SetParameter(espeakWORDGAP,7,0);
    espeak_SetParameter(espeakCAPITALS,20,0);
    espeak_SetVoiceByName("en-gb");

    espeak_Synth(s.c_str(), s.length() + 1, 0, POS_CHARACTER, 0,
                    espeakCHARS_UTF8, NULL, NULL);
```

However, I got two sound cards in my machine(audio and audio1 in /dev) Can I manually set which device to play the sound in program? Many Thanks.

Comment: reading the documentation for espeak_Initialize, the third argument (NULL) is the directory it is looking at - your default audio input.  So point it at `/dev/audio` or `/dev/audio1`.

Comment: @jnbbender I think your suggestion is not corret. According to documentation: path: The directory which contains the espeak-data directory, or NULL for the default location.

Comment: Correct.  I read that as the 'data' directory.  In other words, if you are reading audio data, where is the data, if you are writing - where to.  Give it a shot anyway.